# Type punning doubles into integers and sorted order

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, ieee-754

Say there is a bunch of floating-point numbers, then they can by orderer from smallest to greatest (i.e. sorted).

If I "convert" [1, 2] the floating-point numbers to integers like below, will they keep the same order? I mean, from the point of comparing the actual bits, would it preserve the sorted order?

```
union number {
  uint64_t i; // [3]
  double f;
};
```

Will I get the same ordering, when I sort an array of `number` when sorting according to `i` and `f`?

In yet another words, if:

```
x.f < y.f
```

does it always hold that:

```
x.i < y.i
```

?

[1] from what I read, the actual term for this is ["type punning"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning#Use_of_union)

[2] I cannot simply"cast" (as in `uint64_t i = (uint64_t)f`) as this will simply truncate the floating point number, right?

[3] Does it work for both `int64_t` and `uint64_t`?

Comment: Regarding [3]: It doesn't even hold for type-punning between `int64_t` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan To sort integers, one can compare the pairs of respective individual bits of the two uints and when one encounters the first non-equal pair, the larger number is the one with `1`. And I was just wondering whether the same holds for floats... So the rephrase the question, when comparing two doubles, bit by bit is it possible to sort then is similar way as in the case of ints? I know I can just use `<` to compare the two numbers, it was just a thought...

Comment: You could do bit-by-bit comparison, but with care. First partition based on the most significant bit, then treat the positive and negative doubles appropriately.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan just to check I understood: I should just use two special cases: when the leading bit is zero, then the above example of mine works as expected, and when it's one use the "inverted" comparator (`<` -> `>`), right? But doesn't it work, if I use `int64_t`, instead of `uint64_t`? I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations ..?

Comment: no, `int64_t`, doesn't work either...

Comment: Are you by any change writing a Radixsort?

Comment: @2501 Ha! Yes, I was thinking about it! Any clue how to go about it?

Comment: @EcirHana Let me find that article...

Comment: @2501 "radix sort floating point" gives a nice set of results... To be precise, I was not talking about radix sort exactly, but yes, that would be an application as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In yet another words, if: `x.f < y.f` does it always hold that: `x.i < y.i`?*

No, this will not hold for negative floats. For example, -1 is 0xbff0000000000000, -2 is 0xc000000000000000.

Comment: On platforms with a sign-extending right-shift operator, would `x.i ^ ((x.i >> 31) & INT_MAX)` correctly sort all non-NAN values?

Comment: @supercat Use unsigned and avoid that question. If you validly obtained a signed value then you can cast it to unsigned.

Comment: Is there any "nice" way to generate a value equivalent to `(x & (INT_MAX+1U)) ? INT_MAX : 0` without using arithmetic right shift, a branch, or a multiply?  On many processors, an arithmetic right shift will be the cheapest among those choices.

Comment: @supercat You should really ask a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: My original comment was simply intended to offer an efficient formula for integer values that would transform them so that they would sort like floating-point values, in case you thought such a thing was useful.